# nginx http_push_preload and forwarding headers/cookies

Tags: nginx, http-headers, cookies, http2

I'm experimenting with pushing redirects using nginxs `http2_push_preload on;` directive.

In my application I detect redirects and add a `Link: <location>; as=document; rel=preload` header that matches the `Location` header.

This works well for some redirects, but fails for redirects where the resulting page depends on the value of a cookie (e.g. a cookie containing a session identifier).

While debugging I noticed that the "preload" request is missing the cookies that are available in the originating requests.

In fact only a subset of the original headers are sent in the "preload" request (`Accept-*` and `User-Agent`), headers like `Cookie` and `Referer` are missing.

How can I make nginx forward all headers of the original request to the preload request? Or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this is currently not possible, and likely will never be possible.

I found a similar request in nginx's issue tracker about the forwarding of the `Authorization` header https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1817, which is closed with a `WONTFIX` resolution.

Another ticket, mentioning the `Vary` header was closed as a `DUPLICATE` https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1851

I created another ticket requesting the addition of the `Cookie` header, just to make sure https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1935

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue with other means? I did setup http2 push on nginx and it works as expected. Unless I enable cookie based authentication - since cookies are not passed on to pushed requests, all subsequent pushes fails with 401, as they should. So basically, in my use case (API calls, pushing subresources) HTTP2 push is useless, because I use cookies.